# Xamarin Amazon S3 Uploads

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, mono, xamarin

Has anyone had any experience using Amazon S3 file uploads on Xamarin? It should be simple, but I am having trouble getting it to work. I'm trying to use https://github.com/xamarin/amazon to do my upload of a file like so:

```
try 
{
    var client = new AmazonS3Client ("REDACTED", "REDACTED");
    var transferUtility = new TransferUtility (client);
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
        .WithBucketName("bucketname")
        .WithFilePath(image.LocalPath)
        .WithKey("rodsTest")
        .WithTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
    transferUtility.Upload(request);

} catch (Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString ());
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed. at System.Net.WebConnection.BeginWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1033 at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x0026c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:541

The github repo hasn't been updated in a year so maybe it's just broken? All I want to do is PUT and DELETE files so my next step is to just hit the REST API with RestSharp rather than use a wrapper but surely this is something others have done, can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Check out: amazon s3 file upload using xamarin  c#

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = serviceUrl; // amazon s3 URL                              
config.UseHttp = true;
config.RegionEndpoint =Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1; // your region

AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey,
    secretAccessKey, config);

TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
request.BucketName = s3Bucket;
request.FilePath = filePath; // local file path 

// Test that the path is correct
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(filePath);

System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
await transferUtility.UploadAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```